# SSE Engine Fix loadFromRemoteSources error

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I need to use the SSE Engine Fix mod in Skyrim Anniversary Edition, but after I installed part 2 of the mod I keep getting this error:

> An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to sandbox the assembly, please enable the loadFromRemoteSources switch. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569 for more information.

All of the information I have found tells me how to fix it when creating an app, but since this is a mod I need to know how to either change the files or otherwise fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to load a Special Edition mod in the Anniversary Edition, which will likely cause problems. The Engine Fix mod has not (yet) been ported to Skyrim AE.

[It seems](https://www.reddit.com/r/skyrimmods/comments/qt2tsv/which_fixes_from_the_engine_fixes_mod_would_you/) like the most wanted aspects of the Engine Fix mod are actually going to be incorporated into SKSE, but there is no ETA for this, and the current SKSE changelog (up to version 2.2.3) doesn't make a mention of it either.

---

I did find [this mention](https://forum.nexusmods.com/index.php?showtopic=6640576/#entry82616803) by user (and modder) *Wolfpack49* on [the SSE Engine Fixes plugin page on NexusMods](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/17230) (my emphasis):

> This is an SKSE64 plugin. Therefore, you need to have the correct version of SKSE64 installed to use this mod. If you are playing the Special Edition (1.5.x), you will need the latest SE version of SKSE64.  **If you are playing the Anniversary Edition (1.6.x), you will need the latest preliminary AE build of SKSE64.**

Even thought it was written for version 5.3.3+ (the current version is 6.1.1), since it is still a locked and sticky post, (most of) its contents are likely still valid.

Later on in that same post, the user writes (my emphases):

> **Part 2** [i.e. the part of the mod that goes into your main game folder, and not /Data/] **is compatible with** both the Special and **Anniversary editions of the game**.

When I pick up the game again, I'll see if I can get it to work :)